# Getting a PacketTooBig exception with Java and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I'm receiving a `PacketTooBig` Exception when trying to connect to my MySQL database. I've changed the `max_allowed_packet` to 16MB in the `mysqld.cnf` file, however I am still receiving the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (4739923 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand why you need a packet so large just for connecting.  You might consider using a packet analyzer like tcpdump to see the packet, or setting a breakpoint inside the java jdbc driver to understand exactly why the packet is so large.  If you set a breakpoint, you can start by setting breakpoints on all constructors of com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException, and then when the debugger hits one of those breakpoints, use the use the stack trace in the debugger to see if you can see the packet in the debugger or where to set any further breakpoints.